# Filtering nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I'm trying to filter a nested dictionary. I want to create a new dictionary with values that match items in a list. So far, I've been able to filter the dictionary one level down, on , but I can't find a way to filter a dictionary two levels down.

I managed to filter out keys when the value of 'roll' is not in the `rollList`, but I would now like to filter out keys when the value of 'item1', 'item2', 'item3' are not in `item123List`.
Here's my code:

```
# initializing dictionary
test_dict = {'Nikhil' : { 'roll' : 24, 'marks' : 17, 'extra' : {'item1': 5, 'item2': 3, 'item3': 2}},
             'Akshat' : {'roll' : 54, 'marks' : 12, 'extra' : {'item1': 8, 'item2': 4, 'item3': 3}}, 
             'Akash' : { 'roll' : 12, 'marks' : 15, 'extra' : {'item1': 9, 'item2': 3, 'item3': 1}}}

new_dict = {}

rollList = [24, 54]
item123List = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

new_dict = {k:v for k,v in test_dict.items() if v['roll'] in rollList}  # filter on roll: successfully

# How to filter on values in item1, item2, item3?
new_dict = {k:v for k,v in test_dict.items() if v['extra'] in item123List} # filer on items: unsuccessfully
```

So what I want to get out is a dictionary where the values that are not in in item123list are filtered out of 'extra', and when 'extra' contains no values the 'main' key is filtered out. Here's how that looks like:

```
new_dict = {'Nikhil' : { 'roll' : 24, 'marks' : 17, 'extra' : {'item3': 2}},
             'Akshat' : {'roll' : 54, 'marks' : 12, 'extra' : {'item1': 8, 'item2': 4}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
test_dict = {'Nikhil' : { 'roll' : 24, 'marks' : 17, 'extra' : {'item1': 5, 'item2': 3, 'item3': 2}},
             'Akshat' : {'roll' : 54, 'marks' : 12, 'extra' : {'item1': 8, 'item2': 4, 'item3': 3}}, 
             'Akash' : { 'roll' : 12, 'marks' : 15, 'extra' : {'item1': 9, 'item2': 3, 'item3': 1}}}

new_dict = {}

rollList = [24, 54]
item123List = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

new_dict = {k:v for k,v in test_dict.items() if v['roll'] in rollList}
new_dict = {k: {i: {a: b for a, b in j.items() if b in item123List} if i == 'extra' else j \
                for i,j in v.items()} \
                for k, v in test_dict.items()}
print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Nikhil': {'roll': 24, 'marks': 17, 'extra': {'item3': 2}}, 'Akshat': {'roll': 54, 'marks': 12, 'extra': {'item1': 8, 'item2': 4}}, 'Akash': {'roll': 12, 'marks': 15, 'extra': {}}}
```

Comment: Great, that's almost what I'm looking for. The only thing that is missing is that the main key (Nikhil, Akshat or Akash) should be left out of the new dictionary when 'extra' is empty

Comment: @CrossLord Add `new_dict = {k: v for k, v in new_dict.items() if v['extra']}`